# node.js oauth2 server to server client (google tracks authentication)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-maps, authentication

I'm having trouble finding out how to do something RELATIVELY simple..

I'm writing a node.js application which I would like to utilize the Google Tracks API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/

The tracks API uses OAuth2 to authenticate the server against the API account - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/auth

What I am trying to do is simply to authenticate my application with Google using node.js

The problem I'm having is that every module or framework I can find relating to this topic is all about redirecting a user to google and returning them to the application, this isn't what I want to achieve...  Instead I want to simply hard-code my API credentials into the server and authenticate it directly so it can use the API, I also need some way to keep the session alive when the token expires.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer myself!  :-)

https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt